# Signal desktop does not start

Tags: internet

The icon appears on activities but it does not start.

I also tried the terminal:

```
$ signal-desktop
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 Gnome

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out from this link:
https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/4061

I just uninstalled and then reinstalled from the signal desktop site
https://signal.org/en/download/

with this code:

```
curl -s https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop
```